# Passing one functions variable to another function correctly?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Ok peeps, say I've got something like:

```
Function Get-Reports {
 # Get managers direct report, calls function above
 $DirectReports = Get-DirectReport $Manager -norecurse  | Select-Object samAccountName
 if ($null -ne $DirectReports) {        
     #$LogLine = "Gathering direct reports for " + $Manager
     #Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
 } else {
     $LogLine = $Manager + " has no reports."
     #Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
     #Continue
 }   
}
Function Set-RTGmembers {
    # Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $ou -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.Name -members $DirectReports
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.name -members $Manager
        $LogLine = "Report to " + $Manager + " updated."
        #Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    } else {
        $LogLine = "Could not find group for " + $Manager
        #Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
}

Foreach ($manager in $managers) { 
    Get-Reports
    Set-RTGmembers
 }
```

I get an error saying the Add-ADGroupMember's -members $DirectReports value is empty. I've debug it and it's indeed empty. How do I pass a variable created in a function to another function?  Should I combine them maybe?

Comment: Your functions need to define some parameters which you pass object in by.  Additionally you'll probably want your functions to output some objects  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to return something from the function and pass it as a parameter for the other one. But in your case, the first function is not needed Something like this

```
Function Set-RTGmembers {
    Param(
        $Reports,
        [string]$Manager,
        [string]$OU
    )
    # Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.Name -members $Reports
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.name -members $Manager
        $LogLine = "Report to " + $Manager + " updated."
        #Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    } else {
        $LogLine = "Could not find group for " + $Manager
        #Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
}

$ou = 'SomeOUName'
Foreach ($manager in $managers) {
    $DirectReports = $null #This is to make sure if the Get-DirectReport fails on the last loop, it won't use the last set value
    $DirectReports = Get-DirectReport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object samAccountName
    if ($null -ne $DirectReports) {        
         #$LogLine = "Gathering direct reports for " + $Manager
        #Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    } else {
         $LogLine = $manager + " has no reports."
         #Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
         Continue
     }   
    Set-RTGmembers -Reports $DirectReports -Manager $manager -OU $ou
}
```

Remember that each function has its own scope and the variables declared inside them gets cleared when the function finishes

Comment: Question though, in my original code I'm passing (or trying to pass) $DirectReports to the next function Set-RTGmembers. In your example there's no source for $Reports.  Now $Manager I define up at the beginning of the script but $Reports or $DirectReports was originally a loop that I was trying to turn into a function.

Comment: Inside the function, you can declare the param you're passing using `Param()` at the beginning of the function so those variables belong to the function scope and when you passe them using `-ParamName` (When ParamName means the Variable declared inside the `Params()` section) you set those variables values, therefore, you can use them inside the function

Comment: In case you need a bit more information, you could check here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1) and here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1) or here (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-pass-the-parameters-in-the-powershell-function)